# sshd won't let me enable

Tags: arch-linux, sshd

I want to use ssh on my device, and I can start sshd just fine with `systemctl start sshd`, but I want it to start automatically at boot. The problem is, if I try `sudo systemctl enable sshd`, I get the following error:

```
Failed to enable unit: File /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/sshd.service already exists.
```

How can I fix this issue so that the ssh server starts when I start my device?

EDIT:
Here is the output when I run `sudo systemctl status sshd` right after booting:

```
○ sshd.service - OpenSSH Daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/sshd.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)
```

Comment: I think the service is already enabled

Comment: If the file already exists, then the service is already enabled. If the service is not actually working, then removing that file would probably not be helpful.  You could try `sudo systemctl status sshd` to see what the current status of the service is.

Answer (score 1):

```
 sshd.service - OpenSSH Daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/sshd.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)
```

This indicates the service is currently disabled (= not configured to start) and not running.

The message

```
Failed to enable unit: File /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/sshd.service already exists.
```

indicates that `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/sshd.service` already exists. It shouldn't be there, as the service is disabled according to `systemctl`.

All the files in `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/` should be symbolic links to the actual `*.service` files of the enabled services. Since the `sshd.service` is not in fact enabled, this would indicate that this is either a broken symbolic link, or some other file that has been (accidentally or maliciously) placed in there.

You probably should run a `ls -l /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/sshd.service` to see if it is a broken symbolic link, or a link to some other service, or some other file. If it seems to be a link pointing to some other valid `*.service` file, there might be something malicious going on, i.e. your system may have been hacked. If it seems to be a random unrelated file, it might be the result of a mistyped command executed as root.

If it seems your system has been hacked, see:

- [How do I deal with a compromised server?](https://serverfault.com/q/218005/442837) in Server Fault
- [How do I deal with a compromised server?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/39231/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server) in Information Security.SE

Anyway, since `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/sshd.service` *should* be just a symbolic link to the real `sshd.service`, it should be safe to delete it:

```
sudo rm /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/sshd.service
```

It might be prudent to reload the systemd configuration after deleting the wrong link/file, to ensure `systemd` is not confused by its removal:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

And after this, you should be able to enable the `sshd.service` normally:

```
sudo systemctl enable sshd.service
```

Answer (score 0):

In Arch Linux, I think you have to disable the SSH socket first.

As the root user, do:

```
systemctl disable sshd.socket
systemctl enable sshd.service
```

Answer (score -4):

```bsh
sudo rm /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/sshd.service
sudo systemctl enable sshd
```